# Ruby array - comparison customer_id with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have array of numbers which means governings to acces customer:

Controller :

```
@user_got_these_governings = current_user.governings.map{ |governing| governing.customer_id}

which_customer_is_selected = params[:user][:customer_id]
```

i need to compare customer_id with an array of numbers:

customer_id: 1

Governings: [7,9,6,2,3,1]

if Governings match with customer_id = true

if not = false

Comment: did you try `@user_got_these_governings.include?(params[:user][:customer_id].to_i)`. The 'include?` method returns `true` if there is a match otherwise returns `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
which_customer_is_selected = @user_got_these_governings.include?(params[:user][:customer_id].to_i)
```

`to_i` because you are probably receiving a string in the parameter and you are comparing it with an array of integers.

Comment: its working ! thanks !

Comment: @Tara please take time to mark it as an accepted answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

I think that cleanest way to do it is use [in? method](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/in%3F).

```rb
governings = [7,9,6,2,3,1]
params[:user][:customer_id].to_i.in? governings
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to do it is by using .member? method which tells whether an element is a member of the array or not.

```
Governings: [7,9,6,2,3,1]
Governings.member? params[:user][:customer_id].to_i
=> true
```